# Post or Get, which is more appropriate to call a simple asp page via jQuery Ajax

Tags: ajax, http, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a html page that I need to call another asp page to get the date/hour via an ajax call. Which method would be better or best, Post or Get?

Since I am only retrieving a few bits of data and not sending any data to the page info is one method better or proper than the other?

This is the simple ASP page.

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%>
<% Option Explicit %>
<%=Weekday(Date)%>
<%=Hour(Now)%>
```

And this is the Ajax call to the asp page above.

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: '/v/timecheck.asp',
type: 'GET',
cache: false,
success: function(data){
// do something with the data  
        }, 
error: function() {
//do something on error
            return false;
        }
})
```

The reason I have to make the Ajax call to this ASP page is I cannot query the server direct from this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My rule of thumb when deciding either one is:

- The interaction involve database, POST
- The interaction involve sensitive information, POST
- Requesting simple data, GET
- Sending user input, POST
- Sending/requesting large data, POST
- Clean URL, POST

As you can see, most cases involve POST for many reason. Such as in your case, you could use GET or POST. Either way, jQuery make calling both function easy.

A simpler **$.POST**

```
$.post("/v/timecheck.asp", function (data) {
    if (data.time != "") {
        //retrieve success
    {
    else
    {
        //retrieve fail
    };
});
```

or simpler **$.GET**

```
$.get("/v/timecheck.asp", function(data) {
    if (data.time != "") {
        //retrieve success
    {
    else
    {
        //retrieve fail
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use POST, I think there is a secirity reason in ASP.NET to use POST, but not sure if this relates to IIS (and possibly ASP)

Answer (score 1):

The W3C have a paper with guidelines on when to use GET or POST at: http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet-20040321#checklist

Using a GET request allows the result to be cached by the browser whereas a POST request won't be cached and the page will be re-retrieved every time.

In your code example you are not changing any data as a result of the request and are only providing the day and hour, so using a GET and setting the cache HTTP headers to 1 hour would give you the best performance and reduce load on your server.

Comment: Forgive me for asking but how would I go about do that "and setting the cache HTTP headers to 1 hour"

Comment: You would place the following in the ASP page (to set the page to expire in 60 minutes): `<% Response.Expires = 60 %>`